# Objective-C RegEx-Password-Check is always true

Tags: objective-c, regex, xcode, passwords, expression

I want to check the password's complexity with regular expression.
But it returns always `true`?

The password's complexity is the following. Allowed are:

- A-Z
- a-z
- 0-9
- special characters: - _ , ; . : # + * ? = ! § $ % & / ( ) @
- *No* blank characters

Here is my code:

```
NSString *regExPwd = @"[a-zA-Z_0-9\\-_,;.:#+*?=!§$%&/()@]+";
NSPredicate *pwdCheck = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", regExPwd];
bool isValid = [pwdCheck evaluateWithObject:txtPassword.text];
```

Hope you can help me once again :)

Comment: what is the password which should be `false`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should require that there are **only** allowed characters from the beginning to the end:

```
NSString *regExPwd = @"^[a-zA-Z_0-9\\-_,;.:#+*?=!§$%&/()@]+$";
```